# Understanding this characterization of Schwartz's space

Tags: notation, schwartz-space

While reading up on tempered distributions I came across this definition of Schwartz's space:
$S(\mathbb{R}^n) = \{ f \in \mathbb{C}^\infty : \underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}{sup} \: \underset{\lvert \alpha \rvert < k}{sup} (1+\|x\|^2)^k \lvert D^\alpha f(x) \rvert < \infty \:\: \forall k \in \mathbb{N}_0\}$
Where $\alpha$ is a multi-index of dimension $n$.
I have trouble understanding the nested $sup$s. Am I supposed to read them as one big $sup$, where i try to maximize with respect to $x$ and $\alpha$ simultaneously, or is the order important in a way?
I tend to the further, because I cannot see how it would be possible to attempt to maximize consecutively.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two nested suprema, and as written, they are evaluated consecutively.
So if $f\in C^\infty$ and $x\in\mathbb R^n$, you have
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^n}\sup_{|\alpha|<k}(1+\|x\|^2)^k \lvert D^\alpha f(x) \rvert
=
\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^n}a(x),
$$
where $a(x)=\sup_{|\alpha|<k}(1+\|x\|^2)^k \lvert D^\alpha f(x) \rvert$.

But, fortunately enough, the order of two sups does not matter and you can also regard it as one big sup.
That is,
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^n}a(x)
=
\sup_{|\alpha|<k}b(\alpha)
=
\sup C,
$$
where
$$
b(\alpha)=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^n}(1+\|x\|^2)^k \lvert D^\alpha f(x) \rvert
$$
and
$$
C=\{(1+\|x\|^2)^k \lvert D^\alpha f(x) \rvert;x\in\mathbb R^n,|\alpha|<k\}.
$$
Proving this is a fairly simple exercise using only the definition of a supremum.

Comment: But how do I evaluate the inner supremum? $x$ is not yet determined there, so do I assume x can take all values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and take the supremum of that set w.r.t $\alpha$?

Comment: @iolo, you evaluate it for every $x$ separately. In the inner supremum $x$ is kept constant. Of course the value $a(x)$ of the inner supremum depends on $x$. So: Fix any $x$. Then the supremum $a(x)$ is well defined. Now we have a function $a(x)$ depending on $x$. Only then we evaluate the supremum of $a(x)$.